# Steigerung - Article

Tags: meaning, comparison

Welcher Artikel benutzt man bei Steigerungen (Superlativ)? Ein Beispiel:

> Ihre Tochter ist das größte von allen Kindern in der Klasse.

Warum ist dort "das"? Ist das laut Kindern eben so weil es plural ist? Ich würde "Ihre Tochter ist die größte" benutzen.

Answer (score 4):

Je nachdem, ob das mit dem Superlativ Bezeichnete im Singular oder im Plural steht, wird derjenige Artikel verwendet, den das Substantiv im Singular oder im Plural hätte. Zum Beispiel:

- *der* größte aller Berge (*der* Berg)
- *die* größte aller Partys (*die* Party)
- *das* größte aller Kinder (*das* Kind)
- *die* größten aller Kinder (*die* Kinder)

Answer (score 2):

Hier muss man beachten, dass ein Wort ausgelassen ist. Vollständig (oder fast schon übervollständig) lautet der Satz:

> Ihre Tochter ist das größte Kind von allen Kindern in der Klasse.

Da "Kind", beziehungsweise "Kinder", aber danach genannt wird, wird es oft beim ersten Mal weggelassen und heißt dann:

> Ihre Tochter ist das größte von allen Kindern in der Klasse.

Ebenfalls möglich wäre

> Ihre Tochter ist das größte Kind von allen in der Klasse.

Der Satz

> Ihre Tochter ist die Größte von allen Kindern in der Klasse.

ist ebenfalls richtig, dann muss man "die Größte" allerdings großschreiben, weil es sich um eine Substantivierung handelt.

Rein grammatikalisch ist

> Ihre Tochter ist die größte (Tochter) von allen Kindern in der Klasse.

ebenfalls möglich, nach dem gleichen Prinzip wie oben. Aber so würde man es eher nicht formulieren.

Comment: Der letzte Satz würde allerdings bedeuten, dass alle Kinder eine Tochter hätten und ihre Tochter die größte dieser Töchter wäre.

Comment: Jetzt verstehe ich :) Vielen Dank!

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich So könnte man es auch lesen, stimmt. Ich hätte intuitiv gedacht, dass ein Elternteil die Rolle der "Tochter" in die Schule ausdehnt (Stichwort Helikoptereltern). Und im Zweifel kommt dann gleich ein Schlaumeier um die Ecke, der fragt, wie groß denn nun die _Söhne_ bzw. die männlichen Schüler sind ;)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: "Ihre Tochter ist die größte in der Klasse" kann bedeuten, dass sie das größte Kind der Klasse überhaupt ist, es kann aber auch heißen, dass ein anderes Kind, welches ein Sohn ist, größer ist. Das generische "Kind" schließt eine solche Deutung aus und wahrscheinlich wurde aus genau diesem Grund von Tochter zu Kindern gewechselt. Deswegen sagt man auch "Frau K ist der dienstälteste Minister im Kabinett" und nicht "die dienstälteste Ministerin". Äquivalent, bei Männern, müsste man "der dienstälteste männliche Minister" verwenden, um auf das G. einzuschränken.